# DevDemon Channel Images---When using Rackspace are files also stored onsite?

Tags: channel-images, devdemon

I'm working on a site that is image heavy. I've switched to using DevDemon's Channel Images and am wondering if I use rackspace as a CDN if the images currently on the site are deleted after the copies are uploaded to Rackspace Cloud.

Even if they aren't I could manually delete them, but I want to make sure that copies are not kept in both places. Since the local site mapping option is removed I'm thinking that copies are not kept locally, but it would be nice to have this confirmed.

Currently the site is over 2G and I'm having trouble transferring offsite backups to rackspace via CE Cache. I've been messing with outrageous keep alive times that are not reasonable to keep on a live site. A CDN seems like the answer as long as image copies aren't kept locally.

Appreciate any helpful feedback
Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the Image Transfer feature from the Channel Images control panel?

If yes, the images are not deleted after you move the images. You have to manually delete them. But make sure all images where uploaded correctly!

Note:
If you have a lot of images to transfer (3GB+) we have an internal script that does the transferring outside of EE (or even via shell).
The EE CP has a annoying timeout that cannot be disabled.

Comment: RE: Transfer to Channel images---I've already successfully transferred the images locally.

Comment: RE: images to upload----I have about 1.5G that need to be transfered to rackspace

Comment: Is this the workflow?
1) use Batch Actions within Channel Images CP to transfer images
2) edit channel images field "Upload Location Settings to Rackspace Cloud Files for future entries to upload to rackspace

Comment: I've been migrating files over to rackspace, for the most part things have gone well, but I have a few spattering of jpeg files with the extension in capital letters (.JPG). These folder entries and files DO NOT get transferred to rackspace. I spent time w/ their chat support and they responded "As far as Cloud Files is concerned, the file can be named anything you want and have any sort of extension and it should work" --- If I manually change the file extension, I can re-upload them via EE's edit entry interface and then go back and transfer the images from the channel images control panel.